# xcode 7.0 have segue issue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am newbie for Xcode.
When I click on the button to navigate table view app just hang and its navigate me to AppDelegate page,
Here is my code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let bookPicker = ["Book 1","Book 2","Book 3","Book 4" ]

@IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. 
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell =
    tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customcell") as UITableViewCell!

    if (indexPath.item % 2 == 0){
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }
    else{
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
        cell.textLabel!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.0)
    }
        cell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.textLabel!.text = bookPicker[indexPath.item]

        return cell
    }
}
```

attaching storyboard pics[image]

when i run app and click on button its just take me on following page
[image]

Comment: Where is your numberOfRowsInSection: method ?

Comment: You forgot to add numberOfRowsInSection method

Comment: can you explain please how to do this

Comment: have a look at this https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/

Comment: thanks i did exact same but still same any other suggestion please

Comment: @ddjadav: am i right, that you have 3 elements in your storyboard? For one of them "ViewController" u have the class ViewController in ViewController.swift? This seems to have **no** tableView. But you have a second view -> a TableViewController? And for this, u don´t have any code?

Comment: @ddjadav can u upload your project? i.e. with http://wikisend.com/ ? Than it´s much easier to help...

Comment: sure i'll upload it today

Comment: i have uploded  http://wikisend.com/download/394224/Agadhbodh.zip

Comment: a **little** confused ;-) you have 2 ViewControllers: "ViewController" and "BookViewController". And **one** Swift-File "ViewController.swift". By click on the Play-Button will you call the "BookViewController"? Than you must build a "BookViewController.swift" like  "ViewController.swift" in the sample "SimpleTableView" i advised. And define the segue from ViewController to BookViewController. Do you need more help??? Than i must build a complexer answer 4 u...

Comment: i can't run even SampleTableView project in my xcode. its giving error

Comment: but the error in your project is reproducable for me... It´s cause your tableView in the tableViewController isn´t defined.